# Captcha in Tuleap

Tags: plugins, recaptcha, tuleap

I am very new to Tuleap. I need to integrate captcha. I did and got the success but the problem is, the captcha is displaying on register form only.
I need to display on the register page as well as the login page.
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not possible to do that on Tuleap, captcha is only for registration

Comment: I tried with custom captcha with php but I am not able to set captcha value while generating captcha in session so that I can verify it after submit button.